# How to deal with such OutOfMemoryErrors

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm testing my android App in some devices, and I've noticed a weird behavior in a certain mobile. When I open an Activity (which shows a bitmap) the first time it crashes generating this stack trace:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.perifereia_hpeirou/com.epirus.MonumentProjection}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
at com.epirus.MonumentProjection.onCreate(MonumentProjection.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3492)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:469)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
... 27 more
```

However, if I try to open the activity again this doesn't happen.Also this doesn't occur in any other devices I've tested. I guess the mobile doesn't have enough ram atm and this exception helps it clean memory but this is just my guess.What can I do in order to overcome such a problem?

Comment: Well at least you could catch the exception so the activity does not crash. Load it by code instead through xml. How big is that image?

Comment: it's 1024x1024, I'm loading it by code..

Comment: Are you resizing it? There is also an InflateException. Why?

Comment: Try to add "android:largeHeap" to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml. This will allocate a large heap space for your application if the device is capable of doing that. But this is only a quick solution. You should implement a proper memory management system for dealing with bitmaps. I had similar issues in my Android project as well.

Comment: Yes but this is a problem of the OS right? since it works correctly after It crashes the first time or if I clean the memory before I launch the application

Answer (score 0):

some ideas you can try:

a) Try with a small image to see if it is due to the size of the bitmap.

b) The first cause you have states:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I would also check if the class you are using here is supported by that particular device.

For example I remember an application I developed crashing with devices that weren't google certified because I assumed all devices would have google maps and this is not the case.
I had to add a runtime check before instanciating the object.